# Less than or equal to symbol not bringing desired results in Db2 database

Tags: date, db2, db2-luw

Below query when executed against a DB2 database does not bring in records from 31st March 2019. Ideally it should bring in those records as well since operator used is `<=`. There are rows and it works if I give `<'2019-04-01'` however we do not want to use this and go with `<=`.

```
select wonum, requireddate ,cost 
from workorder 
where reportdate >='2019-03-01'  AND reportdate <= '2019-03-31'
```

Comment: reportdate datatype is datetime and the DB2 database is running on Unix. I'm no sure if oracle compatibility is enabled.

Comment: yes it does exists , if I give < '2019-04-01' then it brings in record of 31st March 2019 however this is not what we want and would like to use <= instead.

Answer (score 2):

This works as designed.
`'2019-03-31' == timestamp('2019-03-31-00.00.00')`
If you really don't want to use `<` (is the `<` sign forbidden in your organization? :)), try the following:
`reportdate <= timestamp('2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999', 12)`

BTW, There is an interesting thing with timestamps in Db2:

```
with t(row, ts) as (values
  (1, timestamp('2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999', 12))
, (2, timestamp('2019-04-01-00.00.00', 12) - 0.000000000001 second)
, (3, timestamp('2019-03-31-24.00.00', 12))
, (4, timestamp('2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999', 12) + 0.000000000001 second)
, (5, timestamp('2019-04-01-00.00.00', 12))
)
select row, ts, dense_rank() over (order by ts) order
from t;

ROW         TS                               ORDER
----------- -------------------------------- --------------------
          1 2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999                    1
          2 2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999                    1
          3 2019-03-31-24.00.00.000000000000                    2
          4 2019-04-01-00.00.00.000000000000                    3
          5 2019-04-01-00.00.00.000000000000                    3
```

`2019-03-31-24.00.00` is a "special" timestamp (with the `24:00:00` time part).
It's greater than any `2019-03-31-xx` timestamp, but less than `2019-04-01-00.00.00`.
So, as Paul mentioned, you may use `reportdate <= '2019-03-31-24.00.00'` instead of `reportdate <= timestamp('2019-03-31-23.59.59.999999999999', 12)`.
Note, that we must specify the fractional seconds length (12) explicitly in the latest case. The timestamp casts to timestamp(6) with data truncation otherwise.

Comment: Interesting, thing about the `24:00:00` timestamp. Postgres behaves the same with `2019-03-31 24:00:00` I wonder if that is mandated by the SQL standard. Oracle however does not allow it.

Answer (score 2):

If `reportdate` is a datetime, then you might want to consider renaming the column to eg. `reportdatetime` or maybe `REPORT_DATETIME`, but hey it's your Database design.

SO, anyway, you could do this

```
 select wonum, requireddate ,cost from workorder 
 where DATE(reportdate) >='2019-03-01'  AND DATE(reportdate) <= '2019-03-31'
```

or

```
select wonum, requireddate ,cost from workorder
where DATE(reportdate) BETWEEN '2019-03-01'  AND '2019-03-31'
```

or

```
select wonum, requireddate ,cost from workorder
where reportdate >='2019-03-01'  AND reportdate <= '2019-03-31-24.00.00'
```

Comment: does the DATE function impacts performance? If yes, the best option may be the last one.

Comment: It does not hurt performance in many queries, check the rewritten query in an access plan to see what Db2 can do to optimize such filters.